# How to integrate a Rich Text Editor into Vue 2 via CDN

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, cdn, tiptap

I am looking to add a rich text editor to my vue2 project but I cannot find one that supports installation as a cdn. I have come across tiptap-vuetify which would be perfect since i use vuetify but it does not seem to support a cdn installation despite the reference in the documents:

https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify

Can someone please provide an example of integrating one of these advance editors as a cdn as I have been wasting hours trying to do so to no avail.

My current method for attempting this is googling the cdn for these libraries (ie tinymce below) and creating a link as follows:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tinymce-vue@1.0.0/dist/tinymce-vue.min.js"></script>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tinymce-vue@1.0.0/dist/tinymce-vue.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Then I figured I could use it as follows in a component:

```html
<editor
  api-key="no-api-key"
  :init="{plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'}"
/>
```

However this does nothing.

Comment: You might be interested in [this comment](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify/issues/146#issuecomment-601548526) made by the author of the `tiptap-vuetify` package.

Comment: Your `editor` component should manually attach TinyMCE to the corresponding TEXTAREA in your template. And also detach it before the component is unmounted.

Comment: @tao so it looks like tiptap will not work with the cdn then :( . Any examples of a rich text editor that will work via cdn? I am open to options. I have tried a few with no success but I also struggle using the cdn for this project so could be using the wrong file .

Comment: The limitation to only working with cdn provided packages sounds obscure and it might be an XY problem. Why not provide them locally, through npm/yarn/pnpm? You could also use [import-map-overrides](https://github.com/single-spa/import-map-overrides/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

Comment: I definitely agree npm or a package manager would be easier. I just started this project with the cdn before npm was allowed to be installed. The project was setup as a c# razor page/vuejs hybrid project and is actually really easy to manage but relying on the cdn is a pain. No build step but i really only use maybe 5 cdns so its not to import and is cached in the users browser.

Comment: @tao so is there no solution to using a rich text editor via cdn in vue2?

Comment: I never said that. On the contrary, I'm quite certain there is. But it's a weird limitation and it sounds like an XY problem. I thought it's worth asking for the reason behind this limitation. Maybe there is a simpler solution for the actual problem.